# CSS3 Crooked Transformation

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

#### Question #1

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sud/YMw3v/1/), the flag raises above the pole

**Current Transition**

[image]

**Expected Transition**

[image]

and restores to expected position after transition is complete, but i am looking for a smooth transition as how a flag naturally hoisted, any suggestions please? Am i missing some thing?

#### Question #2:

Why does the following code do not work

```
#flag:hover{
    top:50px;
    left:100px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}​
```

while the following code works

```
#container:hover #flag{
    top:50px;
    left:100px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}​
```

Am i not supposed to hover on an `<image>` tag? Does CSS do not support it?

Comment: @Andy: I have updated my question, i want a transition like the second image,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`-webkit-transform-origin`](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transform-origin).

I changed your CSS a little bit to account for the changes:

```
#flag{
    position:relative;
    top: 43px;
    left: 120px;

    -webkit-transform-origin: -10px 0px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing:ease-in;

}
#post{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;

}
#container:hover #flag{
    top: 54px;
    left: 104px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YMw3v/6/**

Comment: this is great, but i have another question(Sorry if it sound silly) how did you settle down to value of `-10px 0px` for `-webkit-transform-origin: -10px 0px;` did you do lot of trail and error?

Comment: @Sudarshan: Chrome's developer tools let you tweak values in real time by pressing the arrow keys. I sort of just moved the box around until it looked right.

Answer (score 1):

To answer question #2

The reason your hover is not working is because the flag is behind the poll, so it ignores the cursor.

Add the following to #post

```
pointer-events: none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMw3v/7/

Comment: So, `pointer-events` disabled all events of post so my image flag received events right?

Comment: Have a read through this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events